# Question about 2PL locking

Tags: locking, transaction

New to this stack exchange, I hope this is the correct one. So I am preparing for a final and one of our practice tests had us put locking on two transactions:

```
T1: R1(A), R1(B), W1(B)
T2: R2(B), R2(A), W2(A)
```

adding the locks is easy, you just prepend a RL or  WL before the transactions such that you get:

```
T1: RL1(A) R1(A), RL1(B) R1(B), WL1(B) W1(B)
T2: RL2(B) R2(B), RL2(A) R2(A), WL2(B) W2(B)
```

Where I get lost is that the solution in our practice states the schedule is going to be:

RL1(A) R1(A), T2: WAIT RL1(B) R1(B), WL1(B): WAIT; I assume after WL1 we also need W1(B). Now, from what I understand, in the above case we can only have two possible schedules: T1 -> T2, and T2 - > T1. This seems to imply T1 -> T2 -> T1. Why is that?